# Documenting POJO's through code with Javax annotations and Hibernate validation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, swagger

I have a Spring Boot RESTful API that accepts a JSON as the request body for POST operations.  The JSON is converted to certain objects using a Jackson ObjectMapper.  As more teams use our API, we need to have good documentation that is current.  I have seen Swagger and Spring REST Docs as ways to document an API.  However, I have no seen an example that is helpful to my situation.

I have many POJO's.  They all are inherited from a common POJO and some have many chains of inheritance.  There are many different POJO's that exist and each represents a different event.  The POJO's have annotations like @NotNull and other ObjectMapper annotations to describe the JSON.  We want to document these POJO's or Models through code so that we always have documentation that is current with the code.  Swagger seems too simplistic for our case because our POST API accepts many different models and I have yet to even see an example online of Spring REST Docs.

So basically, my question is: can I document my POJO's with annotations through code?  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't use annotations, but Spring REST Docs has support for [documenting request and response payloads](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads) and [their constraints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-constraints)

Comment: Hi Andy, I have yet to see an example of Spring REST Docs online but I think that it is the best fit for me.  Do you know of any examples of Spring REST Docs in action online?

Comment: REST Docs itself has [several samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/tree/master/samples). Several people have blogged about it too. See http://info.michael-simons.eu/2015/11/05/documenting-your-api-with-spring-rest-docs/, http://yetanotherdevblog.com/introduction_to_spring_restdocs, and https://medium.com/@flbenz/beautiful-api-documentation-with-negligible-overhead-2ba523205f61#.fvvhjp6v0 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JSONDoc:
http://jsondoc.org

I use it in my Spring projects and it is awesome!

Comment: How is it better/worse against Spring Docs or more against Swagger 2?